# Simple Explanation Needed

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I have a friend from Japan who wants a simple explanation.  Which is correct?  "These are their bags."    "This is their bags."

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Have a great time while you are here.

Comment: "Bags" is plural; "this" is not. Therefore it should be "**These** are their bags."

Comment: "Bags" is a plural word. "Their" being a plural pronoun uses "these" which is the plural form of "this". Also "are" is the plural of "is". Simply put, the whole sentence needs to have plural words for correct sentence construction.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

"Bags" is a plural noun.  The pronoun "This/These" is in place of "Bags".  So the pronoun should be plural:

> These are their bags.

You will sometimes hear "This is their bags", especially in speech because you might start saying "This is their luggage", then change your mind and say "bags".  In speech, you can't go back and edit.